# C# HttpWebRequest not working with Bing images

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to get the same HTTP response with C# code that I get with browser. I get plenty of pictures when I'm searching "plate for mechanical calculation" with my browser, but when I delete my 'bing' browsing cookies and download HTTP response with C# code I get zero picture results. Does anyone know how to get the same result of Bing Images with C# code as I get with browser? Bing search API is not an option.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string search = "plate for mechanical calculation";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=" + search + "&qft=+filterui:license-L1&FORM=IRFLTR");

        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        request.UserAgent = ".NET Framework ";
        request.Accept = "*/*";
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        request.Timeout = (int)Math.Round(10.0 * 1000);
        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();


        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Klemen\Desktop\sourceCode.html", responseFromServer);

        MessageBox.Show("The End.");
    }
```

Comment: You need to use the API.  That's like asking "how can I insert a screw without a screwdriver?".

Comment: There is always another way. Even with screws :)

Answer (score 0):

I changed the following line, and got results in the returned html:
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=" + search);

The images are in the resulting html, for example:

```
<img height="170" width="230" src="https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.4OY77AT9EcfuUutKYFdzIwHaLe&amp;w=230&amp;h=170&amp;rs=1&amp;pcl=dddddd&amp;o=5&amp;pid=1.1" alt=" " />
```

You need to parse out the image tags, and then fetch the image results one-by-one. I recommend you use the API instead of scraping.

Comment: The problem is that I need only images with public domain licence.